# Centering a 2 column div around the horizontal center

Tags: html, css

I'm re-jigging a page layout from the late 90s which is a table of tables. Although the content is tables I'm trying to replace the tables which are only for layout purposes with divs. But not with much luck!

In this example I have three tables. The first is a single table which should be centered horizontally. Below that are two tables which should be centered around the horizontal center of the page.

Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/mxvdbbjp

Table B should butt up against Table C (so no blue background) and also Table C's caption should be the full length of the table.

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.L2col {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #00f;
  float: left;
}

.R2col {
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #f00;
  float: right;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #0f0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tab td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">
    <table class="tab">
      <cap>table A</cap>
      <tr>
        <td>some guff here</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="block">
    <div class="L2col">
      <table class="tab">
        <cap>table B</cap>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="R2col">
      <table class="tab">
        <cap>table C</cap>
        <tr>
          <td nowrap>big long nonsense text</td>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: if my understanding is right then you  have an issue with formatting right?

Comment: Is this what you need :: https://jsfiddle.net/jytxshh7/7/ ?

Comment: can you review my post whether it will helpful or not to you?

Comment: Spot on NiK648. Block to 100% and right align table B. Can't believe I got the caption tag wrong as well! Thanks.

Comment: tell me your exact requirement of table I shall do it

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.L2col {
  margin-left: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.R2col {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

.tab {
  background-color: #0f0;
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.tab td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block-1 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f;
  /* width: 70%; */
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
}

.block-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f0f;
  /* width: 100%; */
}

.tab-2,
.tab-3 {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr {
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
}

.tab-1 tr th {
  background-color: #f0f;
}

.tab-2 tr th {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.tab-3 tr th {
  background-color: #f00;
}

tr th,
tr td {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block-1">
    <table class="tab tab-1" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th colspan='2'>Table A</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some guff here</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="L2col">
      <div>
        <table class="tab tab-2" align="left">
          <tr>
            <th colspan='2'>Table B</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="R2col">
      <div>
        <table class="tab tab-3" align="right">
          <tr>
            <th colspan='2'>Table C</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td nowrap>big long nonsense text</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No that's not it. The tables shouldn't re-size.

Comment: tell me exact what is your requirement  I shall do iot

Comment: @Willa Please review an answer or still I missing something.